# TYPO3 backend event listener: Find out if Web > Page module is active

Tags: typo3, backend, typo3-12.x

I want to add a "edit custom record" button to the doc header of the typo3 backend when the "Web > Page" module is active.

This is possible by registering a listener to the [modify-button-bar event](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/12.4/en-us/ApiOverview/Events/Events/Backend/ModifyButtonBarEvent.html) and works fine.

In my event listener class, I obtain the ID of the currently selected page with

```
$pageUid = (int)\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::_GP('id');
```

The problem now is that the button is also shown when the Web > View, Web > List, Web > Info modules are active.

Unfortunately, there are no other GET parameters than `id` and `token`.

How can I find out if the "Web > Page" module is active?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no [official way to obtain the request object](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/12.4/en-us/ApiOverview/RequestLifeCycle/Typo3Request.html) in event listeners in v12, so I have to resort to the global object:

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_REQUEST']->getAttribute('route')->getOption('_identifier');
```

It will return `web_layout`.